# What is the closed form of $\sum_{l=1}^\infty \left(1 -\frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2 + a^2}}\right) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

How can the following infinite series be evaluated to a closed form?:

$$ \sum_{l=1}^\infty \left(1 -\frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2 + a^2}}\right) $$

I tried to evaluate this using Mathematica, but it was not able to find a closed form.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that a closed form exists?

Comment: If yes is the response to @Arthur, do you try integral comparison ? (it seems like hyperbolic functions.

Comment: No, I don't have a reason to believe a closed form exists, but I also don't know how to tell if a series has a closed form.

Comment: Looks like: $\sum _{l=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+a^2}}\right)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{a J_1(a x)}{\exp (x)-1} \, dx$ where: $J_1$ is Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How do you show that?

Comment: Using this formula: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } f(n)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\mathcal{L}_n^{-1}[f(n)](x)}{\exp (x)-1} \, dx$ where: $\mathcal{L}_n^{-1}[f(n)](x)$ is Inverse Laplace Transform.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{\ell}{\sqrt{\ell^2+a^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{\ell^2}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n)!a^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2\ell^{2n}} $$
Thus $$ \sum_{\ell=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{\ell^2+a^2}}\right)=\sum_{\ell=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n)!a^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2\ell^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{\ell=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n)!a^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2\ell^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n)!a^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2\zeta(2n)} $$
The convergence is way faster when $a\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: And of course $\zeta(2n)$ can be expressed using Bernoulli numbers.  But it's still an infinite sum, so not closed form.